# Create a new data frame every time it encounters a value

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to split the data frame based on certain condition, for example, I have a data frame`my_df` which has a variable `k` which has no negative values. I need to split this dataframe `my_df` every time it encounters `0`. To interpret this more clearly below is my code to create `my_df`.

```
my_df <- data.frame("k" = c(0, 0,0, 0.1,1.3,4,5,7,8,11,14,17,10,5,0.4,0,0,0,1.0,2.3,5,7,3,0.1,0))
```

Upon executing the above code my dataframe is as shown below,

```
    row_number k  
        1      0
        2      0
        3      0
        4      0.1
        5      1.3
        6      4
        7      5
        8      7
        9      8
       10      11
       11      14
       12      17
       13      10
       14       5
       15     0.4
       16       0
       17       0
       18       0
       19     1.0
       20     2.3
       21       5
       22       7
       23       3
       24     0.1
       25       0
```

My expected output is split the above data frame when the next value is zero.
i.e, a new dataframe `df1` is created containing the values from `row 1 to 15` similarly another data frame `df2` is created containing values from `row 16 -24`, and another data frame `df3` is created having values from `row 25` this continues till the end of the data frame.

I found that `split()` does the job of splitting the data frame but I do not know how to implement my requirement in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a grouping variable with `cumsum` and `diff`, then `split` the 'my_df' based on it to have a `list` of `data.frame`s

```
lst <- split(my_df, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(!my_df$k) ==1)))

lapply(lst, row.names)
#$`1`
#[1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15"

#$`2`
#[1] "16" "17" "18" "19" "20" "21" "22" "23" "24"

#$`3`
#[1] "25"
```

NOTE: No packages are used.  Only ***base R*** methods are used.

Answer (score 5):

From `data.table` you can use the function `rleidv()` to create a grouping variable:

```
library("data.table")
my_df <- data.frame("k" = c(0, 0,0, 0.1,1.3,4,5,7,8,11,14,17,10,5,0.4,0,0,0,1.0,2.3,5,7,3,0.1,0))
split(my_df, (rleidv(my_df$k==0) - 1) %/% 2)
```

Here is a solution with base `R`:

```
r <- rle(my_df$k!=0)
r$values <- gl((length(r$values) + 1) %/% 2, k=2, length=length(r$values))
split(my_df, inverse.rle(r))
```